# ( Strict ) Relative Path Verification

Tags: java

If Relative path needs to be validated for the path

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Configurator/initlizer/init.xml").available()
```

Question

if the Relative path is valid     ~ avaliable() returns int value  greater then '0'

if the Relative path is invalid   ~ avaliable() returns int value   ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `available()` of a stream doesn't tell you if your path is valid or not. It just sends you the number of bytes that can be read.

Here the javadoc of the `available()` method in `InputStream class`.

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped
> over) from this input stream without blocking, which may be 0, or 0 when
> end of stream is detected.  The read might be on the same thread or
> another thread.  A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block,
> but may read or skip fewer bytes.

You know if your path is valid or not just by calling `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("yourPath");`. Because this method will return `null` if the resource can't be found.

The javadoc of `getSystemResourceAsStream()`:

> @return  An input stream for reading the resource; {@code null} if the
> resource could not be found, the resource is in a package that
> is not opened unconditionally, or access to the resource is
> denied by the security manager.

Comment: `available()` doesn't tell you _"the number of bytes that can be read"_, but the number of bytes that can be read **without blocking**. That is an important difference.